# Есть ли смысл новичку в android разработке учить сначала Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Здраствуйте!
Знаю такой вопрос выгледит довольно нелепо , но все же...)

Есть ли смысл новичку в android разработке учить сначала Java (если он уже знает Python)?
Так как , сейчас все в основном требуют знания Java.
Или в данный момент все же лучше учить такой язык программирования как Kotlin?

Если все же учить Kotlin , то с чего начинать : курсов или книг?

--Если брать книгу , то какую из них лучше взять?

--Если брать курсы , то какой (бесплатный) лучше всего выбрать?

Но некоторые говорят что если учить сейчас Java , а на это уйдет пол года , то все уже перейдут на котлин и что мне делать?

Зарание спасибо за понимание!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учи Java! Java очень хороший язык, который понадобиться во многих областях, да и при работе разработчиком андроид приложений Java всегда будет +

Comment: Но некоторые говорят что если учить сейчас Java , а на это уйдет пол года , то все уже перейдут на котлин и что мне делать?

Comment: Без знаний Java, Kotlin не имеет смысла в андроид разработке, так как в дальнейшем вы обязательно в большинстве случаев во время обучения столкнётесь на примеры и туториалы Java(комьюнити этого языка даёт большое преимущество)
Ну и как говорится век живи - век учись! постепенно вникните в Kotlin если это потребуется, переучиться на него с Java можно за пару месяцев

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы мне очень помогли